# What happens if two parties have a same pair of public&private keys

Tags: key-management, key-generation

we know that we have to create Private key on server and generate its public key and create a certificate. 
But what if we get a private key which someone already has. Isn't the security becomes weak in this case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Simple explanation**

The only way this will ever happen is if you give someone your private key. It will never happen by random chance. **Never.** You'd have a better chance of winning the lottery twice, getting struck by lightning and being [mauled by two gorillas](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1172/411) all in the same day. Instead of worrying about generating a private key that someone already has, you'd be better off worrying about how to protect yourself from lightning and gorillas so you can spend the money you'll win in the lottery.

So as long as you keep your private key private, you will never have to worry about this.

**Scientific Reasoning**

Let's say you are dealing with 1024-bit RSA for your public key system. A good key generator will choose the two 512-bit primes independently, so the probability that any two instantiations of the key generator will choose the two primes necessary for RSA is 2<sup>-512</sup> · 2<sup>-512</sup> = 2<sup>-1024</sup> or about 1/10<sup>308</sup>. That number is so astronomically small that there is no way it will happen in a properly functioning system. Your odds of being struck by lightning in a given year (forget on a given day) 1/1,000,000 (1/10<sup>6</sup>). Probability of getting mauled by two gorillas 2<sup>-120</sup> (see post in Rory's comment). The lottery one is a little harder as it depends on what lottery (as the odds are different for every one), but hopefully you get the point.

**Improper System**

All bets are off. As pointed out in Jeff's comment, this happened in [Debian's version of OpenSSL](http://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571) due to a simple bug which caused the random number generator to be seeded with very little randomness. The result was that people could potentially have the same private keys.

Having the same private key as someone else would allow those two people to decrypt each other's messages, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Private key is generated by some program on server. Is there any chance it will generate the same private&public key for 2 users?

Comment: @Sampath, as long as it is a good key generator, no. So stick to software that is widely used (openssl, openssh, gpg/pgp, etc) and you won't have to worry about this.

Comment: +1 for the amusing statistical commentary, but be aware that it has happened before because of a bad generator. http://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys#How_weak.3F

Comment: added link to @Thomas' gorilla example on crypto

Comment: I hate to say it, but this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I'll have to use your two gorillas statement next time I'm in an argument over GUIDs or some other similarly astronomically unlikely collision event.

Comment: @SteveS, care to explain (or submit a potentially better answer)? The OP did accept the answer.

Comment: Factual evidence/mathematics would make this answer useful. Your answer, as posted, does not provide a way to know that your statements are correct.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, I've added more detail. Hopefully that better shows my point.

Comment: Nice additions. +1

Comment: @mikeazo your statement is good, but it doesn't answer the question. The question was: what happens *if* two keys are generated? Hendrik explains what could happen, although you explain why it's improbable.

Comment: @mikeazo I mean will there be any chance of duplication of public&private key pair.

Comment: There's a typo above.  (I've edited it; but don't have edit privileges).  2^-1024 ~ 10^-308.3 not about 10^-24.   (Remember (b^x)^y = b^(x*y); and since 2^3.32 ~ 10, we have 2^-1024 ~ 2^(3.32*-308.3) = (2^3.32)^-308.3 ~ 10^-308.3; or just 1024*log(2)/log(10) ~ 308.3

Comment: Agree fully with your answer, however, I think there is a small (insignificant) mistake. If you have a 512 bit prime, that doesn't mean that there are 2^512 primes since not every 512 bit number is a prime.

Comment: @Henri - Agree; it was a mistake and I feel silly for not catching it when I saw the other mistake.  But it really is insignificant.  By the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) there are asymptotically x/(ln x) primes smaller than x, so there are roughly 2^503 prime numbers between 2^510 and 2^512.  This would make it roughly 1/10^303.  So if every atom in the observable universe (10^80 atoms) generated a trillion (10^12) keypairs every second since the big bang (4x10^17 sec), you'd only have generated ~10^110 pairs and a collision is still very unlikely.

Comment: I love statistical comparisons, it makes everyone realise how silly their concerns are!

Answer (score 10):

If someone gets access to your private key, he can decrypt messages encrypted for you and sign messages in your name. So he basically can do everything, you can do with the key pair.

Although there had been [bugs](http://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571.en.html) in the past, it is reasonable unlikely that someone else will generate the same key pair.

The main **risk** is, that the **private key gets stolen** by malicious software on the computers the key is stored on. You mentioned, that you do not generate the key pair locally, but on a server. This allows the administrators of that server to access your private key.

While the key might be protected with a **passphrase**, malicious software may replace the key handling applications or sniff keyboard input.